# How to make CSS outline match dynamic element height

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, outline

I have an outline in the header of this page: https://despeaux.consulting/larryhooke/landing/

And I use a media query to change the header text size using vw, but I cannot figure out how to make the inset outline match to fit comfortably.

What is the best way to do this, so I don't have to make a ton of media queries? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to simplify things. You have way more elements than you need. You're setting a lot heights (don't seem to be needed) and some style properties that don't matter. In the end it's all working against you more than it's helping.

Below is a simplified demo of what you can do. Ultimately it's a block level element with regular margins, a border and some padding with the text inside. It resizes based on the size of it's content. Adjust font-size as needed via media query.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: indianred;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
}

.brand {
  display: block;
  margin: 3vw;
  padding: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.brand h1,
.brand h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.brand h2 {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url( 'http://placehold.it/1600x1600/fc0' );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.hero img {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <a class="brand" href="#">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
  </a>
  
</header>
<main>
  
  <div class="hero"></div>
  
  <div>
  
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>
  
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>
  
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>
  
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get it to work using your ideas. Really appreciate it.